# Transforming matrices using tensor transformations?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let us say I started with the matrix 
$$
     A=   \begin{pmatrix}
        x & -y\\
        y & x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
And I wanted to use the tensor transformation:
$$ \bar A^i_j=A^l_m \frac{\partial x_i'}{\partial x_l} \frac{\partial x_m}{\partial x'_j}$$
to transform to plane polar coordinates. What result would I expect? 
Here are my two thoughts:

1. You are simply replacing $x$ with $r\cos(\theta)$ and $y$ with $r\sin(\theta)$ to get:
   $$
        \bar A=   \begin{pmatrix}
           r\cos(\theta) & -r\cos(\theta)\\
           r\sin(\theta) & r\sin(\theta)  \\
           \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. Or we are performing a change of basis, in which case I think we should get: 
   $$
        \bar A=   \begin{pmatrix}
           r & 0\\
           0 & -r  \\
           \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   or something along those lines.

(Please note that I am not asking for a solution to the given problem, I want to know what the this transformation is doing, i.e. is it changing basis etc.)

Comment: Well, it cannot be just replacing the coordinates, because the transformation law is telling you that you should multiply by two other matrices in addition to replacing $x$ and $y$ by their polar expressions (which is implicit in the transformation law).

Comment: Note that the indices in your second equation don't comply with the standard Einstein summation conventions. Paying attention to this may help you understand the problem better, if you recall what matrix multiplication looks like in index notation.

Comment: What about just performing the matrix multiplications? It will take you literally just ten seconds and you will be able to share the answer afterwards.